# Shell Script - can't find string in file using grep

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I've come across some weird problem that I can't solve by myself. I've got two files, content as follows:

**File1.txt**

```
Butterscotch;lkt+4S7Yhzf/g
Sox;WrWMzN6HD
Table;K4yPIK+SFfTFs
tram;YaY3opP9ie
number;e/WwiF5aihUY
Buttler;Nsadlkt+4S7Yhz
wzahwahwah;PYaY3opP9ieH
```

**File2.txt**

```
Butterscotch;lkt+4S7Yhzf/g
Sox;WrWMzN6HD
Table;K4yPIK+SFfTFs
tram;YaY3opP9ie
number;e/WwiF5aihUY
```

I need to find differences between those two files but only for entries that are before semicolon, so I first use `awk` to get those entries:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"}; {print $1}' File1.txt > Output1.txt
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"}; {print $1}' File2.txt > Output2.txt
```

New files contain entries as follows:

**Output1.txt**

```
Butterscotch
Sox
Table
tram
number
Buttler
wzahwahwah
```

**Output2.txt**

```
Butterscotch
Sox
Table
tram
number
```

Then I use `grep -Fxvf Output2.txt Output1.txt > Diff.txt` to print out the differences between Output2.txt and Output1.txt so my file looks like this:

**Diff.txt**

```
Buttler
wzahwahwah
```

Now the tricky part. I need to find and print out to another file whole lines from **File1.txt** that start with entries from **Diff.txt**. I'm declaring a variable and do something like this:

```
variable=$(cat Diff.txt)
grep $variable Output1.txt > Delete.txt
```

So for this example I should get something like this:

**Delete.txt**

```
Buttler;Nsadlkt+4S7Yhz
wzahwahwah;PYaY3opP9ieH
```

But unfortunately I get an error:

```
grep: wzahwahwah: No such file or directory
```

File **Delete.txt** instead of desired data contains:

```
/home/working/File1.txt:Buttler;Nsadlkt+4S7Yhz
```

So it's far from what I need to get. What I've noticed is that when I remove from **File1.txt**

```
wzahwahwah;PYaY3opP9ieH
```

I get no errors and my desired file looks like:

```
Buttler;Nsadlkt+4S7Yhz
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of your `cat` and subsequent `grep` use this `grep`:

```
grep -Ff Diff.txt File1.txt
Buttler;Nsadlkt+4S7Yhz
wzahwahwah;PYaY3opP9ieH
```

Comment: I believe problem is reading file content in a variable and using that variable unquoted afterwards.

Comment: Only thing that bothers me now is why did `grep` work for other entries, but didn't work for wzahwahwah;PYaY3opP9ieH. Nevertheless once again - thank you.

Comment: Hi, It's me again ;) Everything was working great 'till today. I've noticed that when inside my **Diff.txt** I have, for example, only one letter **t**, my **Delete.txt** file would have all entries that have that letter (so there would be Butterscotch, tram, Buttler). Is there a way to secure this, so grep would get only whole words?

Comment: Sure you can use: `grep -wFf Diff.txt File1.txt` Here `-w` for whole word match.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this

```
variable=$(cat Diff.txt)
grep $variable Output1.txt > Delete.txt
```

After the variable is expanded, since it is unquoted the grep command turns into

```
grep Buttler wzahwahwah Output1.txt > Delete.txt
```

Grep only uses the *first* argument as the pattern, and all following args are filenames. Grep found "Buttler" in Output1.txt, but did not find a file named "wzahwahwah"

Comment: Thank You for explanation. I've checked all my other scripts where I use `grep` as I mentioned above, and I'm using it only on files that contain one variable (eg. 0 or 1 to check if script is running or not). So I've made wrong assumption that this will also work with other variables :)